# How to replace all Null values of a dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, null, pyspark

I have a data frame in pyspark with more than 300 columns. In these columns there are some columns with values null.

For example:

```
Column_1 column_2
null     null
null     null
234      null
125      124
365      187
and so on
```

When I want to do a sum of column_1 I am getting a Null as a result, instead of 724.

Now I want to replace the null in all columns of the data frame with empty space. So when I try to do a sum of these columns I don't get a null value but I will get a numerical value.

How can we achieve that in pyspark

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use `df.na.fill` to replace nulls with zeros, for example:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (3,), (None,)], ['col'])
>>> df.show()
+----+
| col|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|   3|
|null|
+----+

>>> df.na.fill(0).show()
+---+
|col|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  0|
+---+
```

Answer (score 71):

You can use fillna() func.

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (3,), (None,)], ['col'])
>>> df.show()
+----+
| col|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|   3|
|null|
+----+

>>> df = df.fillna({'col':'4'})
>>> df.show()

or df.fillna({'col':'4'}).show()

+---+
|col|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+
```

Comment: This func is preferred because you can specify which columns to use, thanks.

Comment: This is also preferred because you can assign it to the same or another dataframe.

Answer (score 9):

Using `fillna` there are 3 options...

Documentation:

> ```
> def fillna(self, value, subset=None):
>    """Replace null values, alias for ``na.fill()``.
>    :func:`DataFrame.fillna` and :func:`DataFrameNaFunctions.fill` are aliases of each other.
>
>    :param value: int, long, float, string, bool or dict.
>        Value to replace null values with.
>        If the value is a dict, then `subset` is ignored and `value` must be a mapping
>        from column name (string) to replacement value. The replacement value must be
>        an int, long, float, boolean, or string.
>    :param subset: optional list of column names to consider.
>        Columns specified in subset that do not have matching data type are ignored.
>        For example, if `value` is a string, and subset contains a non-string column,
>        then the non-string column is simply ignored.
> ```

So you can:

1. fill all columns with the same value: `df.fillna(value)`
2. pass a dictionary of column --> value: `df.fillna(dict_of_col_to_value)`
3. pass a list of columns to fill with the same value: `df.fillna(value, subset=list_of_cols)`

`fillna()` is an alias for `na.fill()` so they are the same.