# PySpark: How to fillna values in dataframe for specific columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following sample DataFrame:

```
a    | b    | c   | 

1    | 2    | 4   |
0    | null | null| 
null | 3    | 4   |
```

And I want to replace null values only in the first 2 columns - Column "a" and "b":

```
a    | b    | c   | 

1    | 2    | 4   |
0    | 0    | null| 
0    | 3    | 4   |
```

Here is the code to create sample dataframe:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,2,4), (0,None,None), (None,3,4)])
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["a", "b", "c"])
```

I know how to replace all null values using:

```
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
```

And when I try this, I lose the third column:

```
df2 = df2.select(df2.columns[0:1]).fillna(0)
```

Comment: You can find more options here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811297/38368

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
df.fillna(0, subset=['a', 'b'])
```

There is a parameter named `subset` to choose the columns unless your spark version is lower than 1.3.1

Comment: wouldn't this give a new df with only one column? anyway to do this in place

Comment: @Fizi in Spark, Dataframe is immutable, which means it's impossible to do this in place.

Answer (score 75):

Use a dictionary to fill values of certain columns:

```
df.fillna( { 'a':0, 'b':0 } )
```

Comment: This is a better answer because it does not matter wether it is one or many values being filled in.

Comment: @ChrisMarotta Does the values type of all selected columns have to be of same type? Could it also be possible: `df.fillna( { 'a':0, 'b':'2022-12-01' } )` where column a is of numeric type, and b is of date type?

Comment: @nam, I suggest you fire up a pyspark terminal and find out

Comment: the behavious that @nam asked for is possible. see the third example in https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill.html