# AWS Glue PySpark replace NULLs

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am running an AWS Glue job to load a pipe delimited file on S3 into an RDS Postgres instance, using the auto-generated PySpark script from Glue.

Initially, it complained about NULL values in some columns:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Can't get JDBC type for null"
```

After some googling and reading on SO, I tried to replace the NULLs in my file by converting my AWS Glue Dynamic Dataframe to a Spark Dataframe, executing the function **fillna()** and reconverting back to a Dynamic Dataframe.

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = 
"xyz_catalog", table_name = "xyz_staging_files", transformation_ctx = 
"datasource0")
custom_df = datasource0.toDF()
custom_df2 = custom_df.fillna(-1)
custom_df3 = custom_df2.fromDF()

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = custom_df3, mappings = [("id", 
"string", "id", "int"),........more code
```

References:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/FAQ_and_How_to.md#3-there-are-some-transforms-that-i-cannot-figure-out

[How to replace all Null values of a dataframe in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312042/how-to-replace-all-null-values-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark/42312884)

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna

Now, when I run my job, it throws the following error:

```
Log Contents:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2017-12-20-22-02-13.py", line 23, in <module>
custom_df3 = custom_df2.fromDF()
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fromDF'
End of LogType:stdout
```

I am new to Python and Spark and have tried a lot, but can't make sense of this. Appreciate some expert help on this.

I tried changing my reconvert command to this:

```
custom_df3 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.fromDF(frame = custom_df2)
```

But still got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DynamicFrameReader' object has no attribute 'fromDF'
```

UPDATE:
I suspect this is not about NULL values. The message "Can't get JDBC type for null" seems not to refer to a NULL value, but some data/type that JDBC is unable to decipher.

I created a file with only 1 record, no NULL values, changed all Boolean types to INT (and replaced values with 0 and 1), but still get the same error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Can't get JDBC type for null"
```

UPDATE:
Make sure DynamicFrame is imported (from awsglue.context import DynamicFrame), since fromDF / toDF are part of DynamicFrame.

Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html

Comment: Can it be because of the column data types?. I remember sth like `fillna()` and `dropna()` is affecting only to columns which have `string` data type by default.. So for example, if the column type is `date` it can still include null values after `fillna()` and `dropna()`

Comment: Have you tried using [DropNullFields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/built-in-transforms.html)? It removes null fields from a DynamicFrame. The output DynamicFrame does not contain fields of the null type in the schema. 

This way you can keep only using Dynamic Frames, which are fine-tuned for Glue jobs, avoiding converting to/from data frames.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling .fromDF on the wrong class. It should look like this:

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
DyamicFrame.fromDF(custom_df2, glueContext, 'label')
```

Answer (score 2):

For this error, `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Can't get JDBC type for null"`, you should drop Null columns.

I was getting similar errors while loading to Redshift tables. After using the below command, the issue got resolved:

```
from awsglue.transforms import DropNullFields
loading= DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice3, transformation_ctx = "loading")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas, and for Pandas `DataFrame`, `pd.fillna()` is used to fill `null` values with other specified values. However, `DropNullFields` drops all null fields in a `DynamicFrame` whose type is `NullType`. These are fields with missing or `null` values in every record in the `DynamicFrame` data set.

In your specific situation, you need to make sure you are using the write `class` for the appropriate dataset.

Here is the edited version of your code:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = 
"xyz_catalog", table_name = "xyz_staging_files", transformation_ctx = 
"datasource0")
custom_df = datasource0.toDF()
custom_df2 = custom_df.fillna(-1)
custom_df3 = DyamicFrame.fromDF(custom_df2, glueContext, 'your_label')

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = custom_df3, mappings = [("id", 
"string", "id", "int"),........more code
```

This is what you are doing: 1. Read the file in `DynamicFrame`, 2. Convert it to `DataFrame`, 3. Drop `null` values, 4. Convert back to `DynamicFrame`, and 5. `ApplyMapping`. You were getting the following error because your step 4 was wrong and you were were feeding a `DataFrame` to `ApplyMapping` which does not work. `ApplyMapping` is designed for `DynamicFrame`s.

I would suggest read your data in `DynamicFrame` and stick to the same data type. It would look like this (one way to do it):

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = 
"xyz_catalog", table_name = "xyz_staging_files", transformation_ctx = 
"datasource0")
custom_df = DropNullFields.apply(frame=datasource0)
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = custom_df, mappings = [("id", 
"string", "id", "int"),........more code
```